# Python - Ipython console in IntelliJ like Spyder

Tags: python, pycharm

I am expecting Spyder's Ipython console equivalent in IntelliJ or PyCharm where i can get results of data structures used in the code. When i am doing data analysis, i run a snippet of code in console like dataframe or variable to see its contents. I am expecting a similar window of Spyder in IntelliJ

[image]

Comment: You can run `ipynb` files in Intellij/PyCharm... why do you want a console?

Answer (score 0):

You can start an Ipython instance by selecting `View` -> `Python Console` in the menu.

It is also possible to set a breakpoint somewhere in your code and choose `Debug` instead of `Run`. In this case you usually see two tabs once the breakpoint is reached. `Debugger` shows the stack trace and variable viewer.

`Console` shows the output of your program. To make it interactive you need to click the (unlabeled) button looking like a command prompt which is selected in the following screenshot from the [official documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-debug-console.html).

[image: screenshot showing the command button].

If stacktrace, variable explorer or console are missing, you can click the `Restore layout` button (above the sorting icon in the screenshot). If you want to see console and variable explorer next to one another or in seperate windows you can drag and drop them as you like.

Comment: That's not IPython

Comment: @endolith It should be if you actually installed IPython for the Python interpreter you selected. Maybe it is disabled in `Settings` -> `Build, Execution, Deployment` -> `Console` -> `Use IPython if available` for you?

Comment: I meant your screenshot.  I do have IPython working in my PyCharm now.